# Desire2Learn Valence API - spaces in file name

Tags: desire2learn

We're trying to pull files and folders from the locker, but the command (/d2l/api/le/(D2LVERSION: version)/locker/myLocker/(string: path)) doesn't like spaces in the file or folder name.  It returns either Bad Request or Invalid Token depending on how we attempt to handle the spaces on our end (i.e. string replace with %20).

How would we retrieve files/folders with spaces in the name?

Comment: Can I ask please what version of the LMS you're using (including service pack)? I seem to be able to create, inspect, and delete folders that have spaces in the name in a locker on a 9.4.1 instance.

Comment: Can you also please let us know: are you using a D2L client library to help you with your authentication, and if so, which one?

Comment: Valence PHP library for authentication and version 10.0.0.

Comment: Hmm. I can make this work with the Python client lib running against a 9.4.1 instance. I'll post an answer here that suggests somethings that might be troublesome, but it might be useful if you open an issue using the D2L Valence issue tracker (https://d2l.fogbugz.com/default.asp?pg=pgPublicEdit) for a more detailed walkthrough.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of some possible problems you're encountering.

When you provide the API path to your D2LUserContext object, you need to pass in only the API path, with internal spaces, not escaped characters. So, a proper route to a file named `test file name` might look like this:

```
/d2l/api/le/1.0/locker/myLocker/firstFolderBelowRoot/test file name
```

to create the authenticated URL for this, you'd invoke

```
yourD2LUserContext.createAuthenticatedUri('/d2l/api/le/1.0/locker/myLocker/firstFolderBelowRoot/test file name', 'GET')
```

That would fashion an authenticated URL you can use to fetch that file named `test file name` from your locker. To fetch its containing folder:

```
yourD2LUserContext.createAuthenticatedUri('/d2l/api/le/1.0/locker/myLocker/firstFolderBelowRoot/', 'GET')
```

Note that when you want to identify a folder in the locker, the `path` parameter *must* end with a trailing slash. (If you're trying to fetch a folder, and you don't have the trailing slash, that might be a source of your issue.)

Once you have that URL, you'll need to use some sort of HTTP library to actually make the call. Our internal PHP devs have recommended using HttpRequest rather than cURL with PHP. Most notably, the URL you should make the call with should preserve the space in the file or folder name in the path component of the URL.

When I test against a 9.4.1 instance using the Python client to do fetches/puts from the locker, or to generate URLs using the user context object and then feeding those URLs into a browser, things seem to work fine. Testing against a 10.0.0 test instance using the Python client also seems to be working.